# Updating Debian 8 Packages

Tags: debian, apt, debian-jessie

I've seen lots of threads all with slightly different answers. Tried all I could but I think they're now all outdated.

So we're running Debian 8 (Can't upgrade as it's not our server) the result of `cat /etc/os-release` is

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Output from `cat /etc/debian_version` is:

```
8.3
```

The `/etc/apt/sources.list` is

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main non-free contrib
deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main non-free contrib

deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/ jessie/updates main non-free contrib
deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/ jessie/updates main non-free contrib
```

Inside `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` I have...

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  244 Feb 17  2016 backports.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   82 Feb  4 09:04 google-cloud-monitoring.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   82 Feb  4 09:08 jessie-backports.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   79 Feb  4 09:08 jessie.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  183 Jul 18  2016 mod-pagespeed.list
```

Inside these there are..... (combined list)

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main
deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie-backports main
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian jessie-backports main

deb https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-monitoring-jessie-all main

deb [check-valid-until=no] http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main

deb [check-valid-until=no] http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian jessie main

### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/mod-pagespeed/deb/ stable main
```

However we get the following error which suggests maybe the sources need changing again to working ones?

```
W: GPG error: http://archive.debian.org jessie Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1587841717
W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-backports/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/jessie-backports/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/jessie-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/dists/jessie/updates/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 130.89.148.13 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/dists/jessie/updates/non-free/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 130.89.148.13 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/dists/jessie/updates/contrib/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 130.89.148.13 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/dists/jessie/updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 130.89.148.13 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/dists/jessie/updates/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 130.89.148.13 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/dists/jessie/updates/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 130.89.148.13 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

The full stack is..

```
root@generational-vm:/var/lib/apt# apt-get update
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg
Ign http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org jessie InRelease
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-backports InRelease
Ign http://http.debian.net jessie-backports InRelease
Hit http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org jessie Release.gpg
Hit http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org jessie Release
Get:1 http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages [2,043 B]
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-backports Release.gpg
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-backports Release
Ign http://archive.debian.org jessie InRelease
Get:2 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages [6,818 kB]
Hit https://packages.cloud.google.com google-cloud-monitoring-jessie-all InRelease
Ign http://archive.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease
Get:3 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org jessie/main Translation-en [4,581 kB]
Hit http://archive.debian.org jessie-backports InRelease
Ign http://http.debian.net jessie-backports Release.gpg
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://http.debian.net jessie-backports Release
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en
Get:4 http://archive.debian.org jessie Release.gpg [2,420 B]
Get:5 https://packages.cloud.google.com google-cloud-monitoring-jessie-all/main amd64 Packages [582 B]
Get:6 https://packages.cloud.google.com google-cloud-monitoring-jessie-all/main Translation-en_US [1,449 B]
Get:7 https://packages.cloud.google.com google-cloud-monitoring-jessie-all/main Translation-en [1,449 B]
Get:8 https://packages.cloud.google.com google-cloud-monitoring-jessie-all/main Translation-en_US [1,449 B]
Get:9 https://packages.cloud.google.com google-cloud-monitoring-jessie-all/main Translation-en [1,449 B]
Get:10 https://packages.cloud.google.com google-cloud-monitoring-jessie-all/main Translation-en_US [1,449 B]
Get:11 https://packages.cloud.google.com google-cloud-monitoring-jessie-all/main Translation-en [1,449 B]
Get:12 https://packages.cloud.google.com google-cloud-monitoring-jessie-all/main Translation-en_US [1,449 B]
Get:13 https://packages.cloud.google.com google-cloud-monitoring-jessie-all/main Translation-en [1,449 B]
Get:14 https://packages.cloud.google.com google-cloud-monitoring-jessie-all/main Translation-en_US [1,449 B]
Ign https://packages.cloud.google.com google-cloud-monitoring-jessie-all/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.debian.org jessie/updates Release.gpg
Get:15 https://packages.cloud.google.com google-cloud-monitoring-jessie-all/main Translation-en [1,449 B]
Ign https://packages.cloud.google.com google-cloud-monitoring-jessie-all/main Translation-en
Err http://http.debian.net jessie-backports/main Sources

Ign http://archive.debian.org jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.debian.org jessie-backports/main Translation-en/DiffIndex
Err http://http.debian.net jessie-backports/main Sources

Hit http://archive.debian.org jessie Release
Ign http://archive.debian.org jessie Release
Err http://http.debian.net jessie-backports/main Sources

Ign http://archive.debian.org jessie/updates Release
Err http://http.debian.net jessie-backports/main Sources

Ign http://archive.debian.org jessie/main Sources/DiffIndex
Err http://http.debian.net jessie-backports/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://http.debian.net jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://http.debian.net jessie-backports/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://http.debian.net jessie-backports/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.debian.org jessie/non-free Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.debian.org jessie/contrib Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.debian.org jessie/non-free amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.debian.org jessie/contrib amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-backports/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-backports/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-backports/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.debian.org jessie-backports/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.debian.org jessie/contrib Translation-en
Hit http://archive.debian.org jessie/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.debian.org jessie/non-free Translation-en
Hit http://archive.debian.org jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.debian.org jessie/main Sources
Hit http://archive.debian.org jessie/non-free Sources
Hit http://archive.debian.org jessie/contrib Sources
Hit http://archive.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.debian.org jessie/non-free amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.debian.org jessie/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign http://archive.debian.org jessie/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.debian.org jessie/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.debian.org jessie/non-free Translation-en_US
Err http://archive.debian.org jessie/updates/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 130.89.148.13 80]
Err http://archive.debian.org jessie/updates/non-free Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 130.89.148.13 80]
Err http://archive.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 130.89.148.13 80]
Err http://archive.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 130.89.148.13 80]
Err http://archive.debian.org jessie/updates/non-free amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 130.89.148.13 80]
Err http://archive.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 130.89.148.13 80]
Ign http://archive.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://archive.debian.org jessie/updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.debian.org jessie/updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.debian.org jessie/updates/non-free Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.debian.org jessie/updates/non-free Translation-en
Fetched 3,002 B in 13s (228 B/s)
W: GPG error: http://archive.debian.org jessie Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1587841717
W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-backports/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/jessie-backports/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/jessie-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/dists/jessie/updates/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 130.89.148.13 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/dists/jessie/updates/non-free/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 130.89.148.13 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/dists/jessie/updates/contrib/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 130.89.148.13 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/dists/jessie/updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 130.89.148.13 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/dists/jessie/updates/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 130.89.148.13 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/dists/jessie/updates/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 130.89.148.13 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Is it Debian 8 (aka 8.0), never updated, 8.1 for example? Check `cat /etc/debian_version`. Also have a look at this, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/598344/debian-8-jessie-keyexpired-1587841717

Comment: Find whoever can upgrade the server and have them do it.

Comment: @Krackout have updated question with 8.3 I believe

Comment: @MichaelHampton unfortunately this isn't our server, so cant be upgraded.

Comment: You said that already, but it doesn't make any sense. Someone can upgrade that server, if not you.

Comment: as it's run by another company, who have no intention of upgrading it, we're stuck with it in its current state

Answer (score 2):

You've shown us `/etc/apt/sources.list` but you have a lot of other apt repositories defined, so those are probably present in files under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

Debian 8 is so old that all of these other repositories are unlikely to still support it. They should probably be removed.

Also the debian-security repository is not yet on archive.debian.org, which is why you get 404 Not Found. For that you should be using:

```
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
```

though it is out of support now so still won't see any updates, it just won't give any errors.

Comment: Hi, Thanks, I didn't know about that directory, I've updated my question with all the sources listed in it. Thanks

Comment: Well you can't make repositories that no longer contain debian jessie contain debian jessie, so my advice to remove them remains the same. Also if you need some justification for getting this server upgraded, the recent sudo local root compromise affects it (if it has sudo installed at all) and it has no update for this. There will be many other security issues.

Answer (score 0):

### Debian 8 (Jessie) Long Term Support end-of-life

https://www.debian.org/News/2020/20200709

> Debian 8 Long Term Support reaching end-of-life
> July 9th, 2020
> The Debian Long Term Support (LTS) Team hereby announces that Debian 8 "jessie" support has reached its end-of-life on June 30, 2020, five years after its initial release on April 26, 2015.
> Debian will not provide further security updates for Debian 8. A subset of "jessie" packages will be supported by external parties. Detailed information can be found at Extended LTS.